Is it really safe to exchange data without a handshake?
I want to be able to exchange data between personal devices within a local network via HTTP.
The point is that I want to use the same pair of personal asymmetric keys on both sides. It turns out that then I can skip the step with checking the trusted certificate. After all, I trust myself by default.
For example, the server supports a method that doubles the received number and returns the result:

P - Payload
SK - Secret Key
T - Time
RID - Request ID

===>
P = 42

POST /double
pub(SK)
SK(P + T + RID)
sig(P + T + RID + SK)

<===
P = 84

SK(P + T)
sig(P + T + RID)


The sender generates a symmetric key and a request ID. Encrypts the symmetric key with a public key. And encrypts the request time, ID, and body (the number we want to double) with a symmetric key. And adds a signature of all data at the end.
It turns out that now if the recipient has the same pair of asymmetric keys, then he will be able to:

decrypt the sent symmetric key
make sure that the data was sent by the owner of the same asymmetric key, because there is a signature with a private key
by the sent time, you can determine that the request is out of date, because the time is now not only in the encrypted part, but also in the signature
by the sent ID, you can understand that the request was sent again (for example, intercepted by a man in the middle), and there is no need to store such IDs on the server side longer than the lifetime of the request

And the person in the middle will only be able to save the entire request in encrypted form. He will not be able to decrypt or forge it without an asymmetric key. And a resend will be rejected by the server, taking into account the time and ID tied to the request.
Was it really possible to cover all corner cases? How can such a scenario be tested for vulnerabilities?
